# Display a loader every time a page is submitted MVC Asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

How can I load a image or text every time a page is submitted in MVC Asp.net? So, basically I don't want to repeat code in every page, I'd like to display a image or text when a form (no matters where into the app) is submitted, and/or a better way to let the users the page is loading.

here is the code in _layout.cshtml

```
<div class="spinner" style="display:none">
    <div class="center-div">
        <div class="inner-div">
            <div class="loader"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@RenderBody()
```

this is the JavaScript I coded to capture all submit buttons:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document.querySelectorAll("button[type=button]")).click(function () {
            $('.spinner').css('display', 'block');
        });
    });
</script>
```

And finally a simple CSS:

```
<style>
    .center-div {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        margin-left: -150px;
        margin-top: -150px;
    }

    .spinner {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 999;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: Black;
        filter: alpha(opacity=60);
        opacity: 0.6;
        -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    }

    .loader {
        margin: auto;
        border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border-top: 16px solid #15a0ec;
        border-bottom: 16px solid #15a0ec;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
        animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    }

    .inner-div {
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 15px;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 2%;
        width: 150px;
    }

    @@-webkit-keyframes spin {
        0% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        }

        100% {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }

    @@keyframes spin {
        0% {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }

        100% {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }
</style>
```

I tried this but it's not working at all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of Ajax Form Submit :

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, xhr, options) {

     $('.spinner').css('display', 'block');

}).ajaxComplete(function (event, xhr, options) {    

    $('.spinner').css('display', 'none');

}).ajaxError(function (event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {    

     $('.spinner').css('display', 'none');

});
```

This will handle loader in all your Ajax calls.

In case when you want to show loader until the page is loaded completely then :

First, remove "display:none" from your spinner div

```
  <div class="spinner">
        <div class="center-div">
            <div class="inner-div">
                <div class="loader"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and then in JS :

```
<script>
        $(window).on('load', function () {
            $('.spinner').css('display', 'none');            
        });
</script>
```

Comment: I am not using Ajax calls. :(

Comment: Do you want to show the loader till the content is loaded and hide it afterwards ?

Comment: Basically when I submit from any view

Comment: But if you are not using Ajax the page will re-load, which will not solve your purpose.

Comment: So, there is no way to display a loader in _Layout when I submit a form from any view unless I use Ajax?

Comment: Should I use Ajax for all the views then?

Comment: check the second option in updated answer. And Yes, you will have to use Ajax if you do not want your page to be reloaded after every form submit.